# Continuity in function (2 variables)

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Given ,

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ 
\end{cases} $$

We need to check whether the function is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not.

Applying the definition I get:

$\epsilon$  = $\sqrt\delta$.

but I do not know if I'm right

Comment: What is $f$ in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.

Set $\delta = \varepsilon$. For $\|(x,y)\|_2 < \varepsilon$ we have:

$$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| = \frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{\|(x,y)\|_2} = \underbrace{|x|}_{<\varepsilon} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{|y|}{\|(x,y)\|_2}}_{\le 1} < \varepsilon$$

Thus, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

---

We could also arrive at this result using polar coordinates $x = r\cos\phi$, $y = r\sin\phi$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi}{r} = \lim_{r\to 0} r \cdot \underbrace{\cos\phi\sin\phi}_{\in [-1,1]} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

using $AM-GM$ we get $$x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$$ so $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq \sqrt{2|xy|}$$ thus 
$$\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{2|xy|}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|xy|^{1/2}$$ this tends to Zero if $$x,y$$ tends to zero